# What is a right way to restore secured string from text file via Powershell

Tags: powershell, securestring

I would like to avoid using password in plain text via using cmdkey and simpliest way to achieve that, from my point of view, is to copy coded string to a text grabbed from ConvertTo-SecureString and save is to txt file and then import this back using ConvertFrom-SecureString. Problem is that when I'm trying to convert secured string back from what is stored in text file and then print output it's different from one which is saved in text file. I'm planning to use this technique on different computers, is it because different machines recover secured string differently or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot travel with that data. When it is converted to secure string that string is only able to be decrypted on that computer by that specific user account, unless you specify key data both when you convert to, and from secure string. Providing that key data defeats the purpose more or less since at that point anybody with that key data can convert the string data to plain text.

Comment: I've read this post [link](https://www.techtarget.com/searchitoperations/tutorial/How-to-secure-passwords-with-PowerShell) and made a conclusion that providing specific key depends does not help either and crypting/decrypting result will be different from one machine to another as well. Am I right or miss something?